# The method setOnAction((<no type> e) -> {}) is undefined for the type Button

Tags: java, javafx

So I'm trying to get this window to display. And it's giving me errors about the methods not being defined for type Button. I'm not sure why because this code is copied directly from a tutorial. Worked on his IDE but not in mine. He was using intellij and I am using Eclipse.

### Errors are :

```
    closeButton.setOnAction(e -> window.close());
```

> The method `setOnAction((<no type> e) -> {})` is undefined for the type `Button`

---

```
    layout.getChildren().addAll(label, closeButton);
```

> The method `addAll(int, Collection<? extends Node>)` in the type `List<Node>` is not applicable for the arguments `(Label, Button)`"

---

```
import java.awt.Button;

...

public static void display(String title, String message) {
    Stage window = new Stage();

    //Block events to other windows
    window.initModality(Modality.APPLICATION_MODAL);
    window.setTitle(title);
    window.setMinWidth(250);

    Label label = new Label();
    label.setText(message);
    Button closeButton = new Button("Close this window");
    closeButton.setOnAction(e -> window.close());

    VBox layout = new VBox(10);
    layout.getChildren().addAll(label, closeButton);
    layout.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);

    //Display window and wait for it to be closed before returning
    Scene scene = new Scene(layout);
    window.setScene(scene);
    window.showAndWait();
}
```

Comment: What package did you import to use `Button`? What version of Java are you compiling your code under?

Comment: @DavidYee I used import java.awt.Button; and I'm compiling under 1.8

Comment: please put that information in your question, too, don't just answer a comment. It's important details that people need in order to answer the question without having to read through a comment thread.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are using the wrong `Button` class. The `Button` class you are referencing is the [AWT `Button`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/Button.html). Instead, you should be using the [JavaFX `Button`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/Button.html).

Change your import statement to the following:

```
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
```

Comment: That fixed it. Thanks so much!

Comment: @DevinMatté then you should upvote and accept the answer